# Rails ActionMailer auth error when run from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I set up a UserMailer and I am able to send emails from the rails console.

**UserMailer.testmail(User.first).deliver_now** works fine from the console, but when I run the same method in a controller from a 'link_to ... method: :put' it returns following error:

535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed:
Rails.root: ...

Can anyone help me send mails from a link?

edit: That was in development, just tried in production and it doesn't work through the console either.

Comment: Please post full backtrace of error message so it will be easy to figure out what error is..

Comment: I played around a bit and found where it went wrong, I was overriding the delivery options of the mailer with user_name: 'ABC <example@email.com>' which returns the auth error. Do you know if there is any way to declare a custom sender name without messing with the delivery options? Alright got it, declare it in the "from" part..

Comment: Yes you can declare sender name as mail(from: 'Sender Name <sender@example.com>')..